# is Nokia 's MeeGo 1.2 "Harmattan" having JVM?

Tags: qt, nokia

is Nokia 's MeeGo 1.2 "Harmattan"  having  JVM?  if it has, what is the difference between application developed by SDK  and tha Applications developed by J2me for JVM?

Answer (score 1):

No, not officially. MeeGo's intended development environment is Qt.

You may want to read this thread on the Meego-dev list:
http://lists.meego.com/pipermail/meego-dev/2010-March/thread.html#648

Qt with C++ is not terribly unlike Java, so may be worth the time to learn. It has the added benefit of generating native code for the target platform, which theoretically improves performance.

Comment: "theoretically improves performance"... when used correctly. But that goes for anything really.

Comment: has nokia closed meego after N9? wont they release new mobile based on meego?